# Was Lincoln's Mom the best wrestler in Kentucky?

Tags: history

The author of *Lincoln's Battle* makes this claim: [source](http://www.salon.com/2012/12/12/abraham_lincoln_bare_knuckle_brawler/)

> And Lincoln’s mother was the best wrestler in Kentucky. I have a quote in the book from a judge who says, “Oh yeah, I got my butt whooped years ago by Mrs. Lincoln.”

The author even seems somewhat skeptical of this assertion.  Any validity to this claim?

Comment: As a side note, having your "butt whooped" doesn't necessarily mean you got in a fight or wrestling match. It could be a metaphor for being bossed around by Mrs. Lincoln or it could have the more literal meaning of being spanked as a child by Mrs. Lincoln, which wouldn't be that unlikely given the time period we are talking about.

Comment: @KevinWells In a section of an article that deals exclusively with the claim as presented, corporal punishment and your other explanations make literally no sense.  That's why we post the source of the claim.

Comment: If that were definitely the context for the quote I would agree with you, but the source that you linked doesn't give sufficient context for the judge's quote to rule out the other interpretations

Comment: You are both arguing that the source's evidence is insufficient for a skeptic to accept the claim. Let's move on.

Comment: Were phrases "oh yeah" and "butt whooped" even in circulation back in the early 19th century?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The claim in the OP is paraphrasing a historic source.

[Usher Ferguson Linder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usher_F._Linder) wrote, in [Reminiscences of the Early Bench and Bar of Illinois](https://books.google.com/books?id=K6MUAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=%22one+of+the+most+athletic+women+in+Kentucky%22&source=bl&ots=Oh6ABG3UCf&sig=DwPBqBrLXYtddxd_v-v7BhNtjFs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH5q_AiJ3QAhVJhlQKHesqDtQQ6AEIITAC#v=onepage&q&f=false) (1876):

> His mother, whose maiden name was Nancy Hanks, was said to be a very strong-minded woman, one of the most athletic women in Kentucky. In a fair wrestle, she could throw most of the men who ever put her powers to the test. A reliable gentleman told me he heard the late Jack Thomas, clerk of the Grayson Court, say he had frequently wrestled with her, and she invariably laid him on his back.